# For which values of $n$ can $x^n+y^n$ be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x, y$ and $n$ be positive integers. Using [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLastTheorem.html) we can show that $x^n+y^n$ can't be a perfect square if $n$ is divisible by $4$, but when $n=3$ we have some simple solutions like $$1^3+2^3=3^2 \\ 2^3+2^3=4^2$$

I have conjectured that

> There are nontrivial integer solutions for $x,y$ and $z$ in $$x^n+y^n=z^2,\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\,\,\,\,\text{which is not a multiple of 4.}$$

How can I attempt to prove this? A hint or a reference would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [Farmat Last Theorem for $n=4$](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com%2F2005%2F05%2Ffermats-last-theorem-n-4.html&ei=PxEVVaX0K8T48QWlk4CIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGzbRDLeaZA4stLiUw1YyIosEZE6g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that a solution $(x,y,z)$ is trivial if $xyz = 0$ or $xyz = \pm 1$, and is primitive if $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$.

Then (theorem): if $n \geq 4$, there are no nontrivial primitive solutions to $x^n + y^n = z^2$.

This is proved in Darmon-Merel, "Winding quotients and some variants of
Fermat’s Last Theorem", which can be found [here](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~loic.merel/winding.pdf) on Merel's webpage. Simpler cases (for instance, $n \equiv -1 \mod 4$, or $n \leq 7$) had been solved before their paper. They give a brief discussion of the history of the problem in the paper.

Comment: As for why we want primitive solutions: let $n$ be odd. Then $x=y=2, z=2^{(n+1)/2}$ is a solution, but a cheap and uninteresting one.

Comment: Thank you. Also, what is $p$ ? and can you give me a link for that paper ?

Comment: [I found it. Thank you very much.](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebusers.imj-prg.fr%2F~loic.merel%2Fwinding.pdf&ei=ahIVVciRG8j88AX77YDoDw&usg=AFQjCNEGP6ZQEQlJK7Nd5MDmM7bm2zEDnw)

Comment: @Nilan Typo; it's been fixed. Paper is now linked in the answer.